# SharePoint list item with checkbox databinding possible?

Tags: data-binding, sharepoint-2007, splistitem

In SharePoint I can tee up a binding to an edit field like this below. When the form posts back the changes are automatically persisted to the underlying list item.

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="Field1" FieldName="MySPListItemFieldName" ...
```

So this works great for RichHtmlFields, but say I've got a Yes/No (boolean) field in the same list item, is there a similar construct to bind that field to a check box control in a similar way?

My goal is to not have to throw down a line of c# to transfer the value of the control to the field, I want it to be automatic like RichHtmlField. It seems like there has to be a straight forward way of doing this since SharePoint does this itself with its internal list item editing page (EditForm.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a BooleanField control on your form:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.booleanfield.aspx

Just set the FieldName to that of your Yes/No column, should work fine.

Comment: Well that was easy! I didn't see this at all in the SharePoint designer controls toolbox.

Comment: Hmm, the field should've been listed with the other controls that are available, but then again, I rarely use the GUI designer.